# How to click on long press on camra screen and take a picture android

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to take picture on long press on camera screen any one help me

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mirrorlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonlayout" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_prevew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the [link](http://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/working-with-camera-on-android-sdk/)

In this example he is using a framelayout for camera screen & button for click action.

So modify it & setOnLongClicklistener for framelayout directly

It may help U..